# Label text displayed underlined at Y-axis in highcharts

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, highcharts, ionic-framework

I am getting y-axis label text underlined with blue color in iphone for drawing highchart.

Following is my code

```
  $scope.chartConfig.options.yAxis.splice(dataset.id,0,{
        id: dataset.id,
        lineColor : dataset.pointColor,
        lineWidth : 1,
        title: {
            text: null,
            style: {
               color: dataset.pointColor
            }
        },
        labels: {
            style: {
                color: dataset.pointColor,
                fontSize:'10px'
            },
            useHTML : true,
            formatter: function() {
            if(this.value > 99 || this.value < -99){
                var yAxisValue = parseFloat(this.value);
            var valueStringLength = (yAxisValue).toString().split(".")[0].length;
            var labelValue = (this.value/Math.pow(10, valueStringLength-1)).toFixed(2);
            labelValue = labelValue + "<span>&times;</span>10^"+(valueStringLength-1);
            return labelValue ;
        }else{
            return Math.round(this.value);
        }
    },
    align: 'center',
    x: indexPositive?32:-32
  },
  opposite: indexPositive
});
```

When I return value from else part of `formatter` function, I get the Label text **underlined and in blue color**. I have tried to insert `textDecoration: 'none'` in style attribute but no effect on it. I tried with other way by adding line `Highcharts.Tick.prototype.drilldown = function(){};` in the code but no effect.

I am surprised with the behavior of label text. How internally it is applying style to text?

Please help..

Thanks.

Comment: could you please check the value of 'this.value' in else loop?

Comment: Does it happen only in iPhone? Do you use `drilldown.js` plugin from Highcharts? There is nothing wrong with your current code, so somewhere else must be the problem. As for the solution, try this: `return '<span style="text-decoration: none">' + labelValue + '</span>';`

Comment: I concur with the thought on `drilldown.js` ... this example shows how the labels are linked by default to tell the user they can take an action to "drill down" further into the data (http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-drilldown). If you are using `drilldown.js`, I would recommend against removing the underlines unless you're giving your users another way of telling them they can take an action on that label (from a usability standpoint).

Comment: Hello...@Pawal...  applying '<span style="text-decoration: none">' + labelValue + '</span>' didnt worked....

Comment: I have taken a look at `drilldown.js` but I haven't found any useful to change style of y-axis label....!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks friends for all your response, however my friend solved this problem by putting following code.

```
return "<div><span>"+Math.round(this.value)+"</span></div>";
```

in the place of

```
return Math.round(this.value);
```